# Insert values from same table is it possible?

Tags: sql-server

Hi I want to insert a table values from the same table is it possible?

Ex : I'm trying to insert like this

insert into emplyeee values (select # * from employee)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

leave out the `value` keyword:

```
insert into employee
select * from employee
```

Assuming there are no unique or primary key constraints of course.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

```
insert into employee (Column1,Column2,Column3) 
select Column1,Column2,Column3 from employee
```

You should specify all the non-identity columns if you have an identity field, as you will not be allowed to insert the identity values explicitly.